# I would like to replace a pattern with another pattern found in the same line

Tags: text-processing

I would like to replace the second tab-delimited field with the first underscore delimited field found in the same line

Input

```
Cho1_01:C4WMNACXX:1:250326554   1   2 4 2 -9 1 1 4 3 1 4 1 -9 4 1 4 1 3 1 -9 4 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 1 1 3  
Elq3_04:C4WMNACXX:1:250326565   9   2 2 4 -9 3 -9 1 2 3 4 4 3 1 1 -9 3 3 3 -9 4 4 -9 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 1
```

Desired output

```
Cho1_01:C4WMNACXX:1:250326554   Cho1    2 4 2 -9 1 1 4 3 1 4 1 -9 4 1 4 1 3 1 -9 4 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 1 1 3  
Elq3_04:C4WMNACXX:1:250326565   Elq3    2 2 4 -9 3 -9 1 2 3 4 4 3 1 1 -9 3 3 3 -9 4 4 -9 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 1
```

Comment: Are *all* the fields tab-delimited, or just the first two?

Comment: Just the first two, the rest are space-delimited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `split` function in `awk`. This is one of the ways that this can be achieved. For exampleHere

```
awk '{split($1,arr,"_"); $2 = arr[1]; print}' file
```

Here we use `split` and use `_` as an array separator. Then the second field is substituted by `arr[1]` which holds the value you want.

Comment: this works, but no fields are being **swapped**, so what's the point of the temp variable?  setting `arr[1]=temp` doesn't affect the output, or anything else.  `awk '{split($1,arr,"_"); $2 = arr[1]; print}'` produces the same output.  probably should use `-v OFS='\t'` to get tab separated output, too.

Comment: @cas  you are absolutely right. I'm not sure how I managed to mess that up.  Thanks for the useful comment.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/^([^_]*)(_[^\t]*\t)([^\t]*)/\1\2\1/' <file
```

POSIXly:

```
TAB=$(printff '\t')
sed -e "s/^\([^_]*\)\(_[^${TAB}]*${TAB}\)\([^${TAB}]*\)/\1\2\1/" <file
```

Comment: Could you add a brief explanation of the GNU sed option?

Comment: @jl-blancopastor: `-E` option just enable extended regular expression, you can use parentheses to group matching lik `(foo)` instead of `\(foo\)`.